# как получить html и css определенного блока

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

мой проект на vue и я хочу добавить кнопку, при нажатии которой можно получить html и css определенного блока. Как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод в вашем компоненте

```
methods: {
    getHtmlContent: function (event) {
      const htmlContent = document.querySelector('.the-element-you-want').innerHTML;
      const element = document.querySelector('.the-element-you-want');
      const elementCss = window.getComputedStyle(element , null);
    }
  }
```

Кнопка

```
<button v-on:click="getHtmlContent">Get html</button>
```

Comment: а как же стили?

Comment: Упс, забыл. Обновил

Comment: @myscode спасибо, моя задумка в том чтобы пользователь, мог сам сконструировать себе какой-нибудь блок. и при нажатии скопировал html и css этого элемента. Такой способ подойдет? проверить сам смогу позже:(

Comment: в приципе да. Сможете из массива свойств и их значений сгенерировать css

Answer (score 0):

Для получения стиле блока средствами JS можно использовать `getComputedStyle`

[Описание в документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

А для получения HTML кода элемента можно использовать `outerHTML`

[Документация](https://learn.javascript.ru/basic-dom-node-properties#outerhtml-html-elementa-tselikom)